# NSFetchedResultsController controllerDidChangeContent never called

Tags: swift, core-data

I am having trouble implementing a very basic `NSFetchedResultsController`.
I have the following super simple Demo app set up with just one view and a button, the CoreData stack implementation is the one auto-generated by Xcode.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set up the NSFetchedResultsController.
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Demo>(entityName: "Demo")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)]
        let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext:  appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        // Delegate is set!
        controller.delegate = self

        do {
            try controller.performFetch()
            print(controller.fetchedObjects?.count) // This prints the correct count when restarting the app.
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to fetch entities: \(error)")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func addNewPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Demo", into: appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext)

        // Save the context
        do {
            try appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        print("called") // NEVER CALLED!
    }

}
```

Whenever `addNewPressed` is called, a new object is inserted and saved. However, `controllerDidChangeContent` is never called.

Am I missing something trivial here?

Thanks

Comment: `let controller = ...` creates a *local variable* and it released as soon as viewDidLoad returns. You should make that an instance variable.

Comment: wow... such a simple mistake. Thanks! Could you make this an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(...)
```

creates a *local variable*  in `viewDidLoad`. As soon as the program control
returns from that function, no strong references to the fetched results controller
exist anymore, and it is destroyed.

The solution is to make `controller` an *instance property* of the view controller.